# "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil; GitHub repo showing app; SwiftUI

Tags: api, swiftui, urlsession

I need to create an app that will be able to return all the repositories that a GitHub user owns.

I created an app that contains of 3 files:
CONTENT VIEW

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var netManager = NetworkingManager()
    
    
    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(netManager.owner) { item in
                    Text(item.reposUrl)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

API KEYS

```
import Foundation

struct Root : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let items : [Repository]
}

struct Repository: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, fullName: String
    let owner : Owner
}

struct Owner : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let reposUrl : String
}
```

DECODERS (since I know I should need another one later, unless I can abstract this one enough)

```
class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published var owner = [Owner]()
    
    init() {
            loadData()
        }

        func loadData() {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos") else { return }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Owner.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
                
            }.resume()
        }
        
    }
```

The code runs fine, but I don't get any results (the first screen is blank) and I would like to see a list of the chosen user repos there. Could you please help me decode the dictionary?

I also wonder if the problem doesn't lie with that I didn't use convertFromSnakeCase key Decoding Strategy either, but I don't know how to put it there when the JSONDecoder is wrapped in a constant.

Comment: the model structs you have do not match the json data you get from github. Copy and paste the json data (eg. from your browser) into https://app.quicktype.io/ and use the generated structs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a minimalist working example code, try this:

```
struct Repository: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, fullName: String
    let owner: Owner
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, owner
        case fullName = "full_name"  // <-- here
    }
}

struct Owner : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let reposUrl : String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case id
        case reposUrl = "repos_url"  // <-- here
    }
}

class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published var owner = [Owner]()
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // <-- here
                do {
                    let repos = try JSONDecoder().decode([Repository].self, from: data)  // <-- here
                    repos.forEach{ self.owner.append($0.owner) }
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
           }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var netManager = NetworkingManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(netManager.owner) { item in
                Text(item.reposUrl)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you a list of `"https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos"` because that is what the data consist of.

EDIT-1: to list all repos

```
class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject{
    @Published var repos = [Repository]() // <-- here repos
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // <-- here
                do {
                    self.repos = try JSONDecoder().decode([Repository].self, from: data)  // <-- here
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var netManager = NetworkingManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(netManager.repos) { repo in
              VStack {
                Text(repo.fullName).foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text(repo.owner.reposUrl)
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One small amendment, after my recent project, in the solution suggested above it is better to use [weak self] if no more parameters are passed in the closure:

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] (data, _, _) in
        guard let self = self, let data = data else { return }
```

instead of

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/jacobtoye/repos") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
```

Thanks to that approach, you can prevent memory leak, which might make your app slower at the end of the day.